# c++ const_cast<char*> same binary different results on 2 64bit ms os's

Tags: c++, 64-bit

I have the following function (shortened for brevity) :
(PortNo = 12345)

```
void startparser(){
    std::ostringstream convert;
    convert.str("");
    convert << '"' << "c:\\some\\file path\\a_program.exe" << '"' << " " << PortNo;
    std::cout << "DEBUG2 " << convert.str() <<std::endl;
    char *cmd = const_cast<char*> ( convert.str().c_str() );
    std::cout << "DEBUG3 " << cmd <<std::endl;
}
```

I compile on w10 64bit with eclipse MinGW64 and the code outputs

DEBUG2 "c:\some\file path\a_program.exe" 12345

DEBUG3 "c:\some\file path\a_program.exe" 12345

Now if I copy the binary and the 3 dll's it uses to a win7 64 machine and run the same code I get

DEBUG2 "c:\some\file path\a_program.exe" 12345

DEBUG3 .

I don't get it? I need cmd to be an LPTSTR . Can someone please clarify? Another method to get my LPTSTR is fine too.

Comment: `const_cast<char*>` I cry everytim

Comment: `convert.str()` is a temporary, and you save a pointer to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a temp object: `ostringstream::str()` returns an object which is destroyed immediately. Therefore after this line

```
char *cmd = const_cast<char*> ( convert.str().c_str() );
```

the `cmd` points to memory which was used for a temp object and is therefore no longer valid.

If you really need to operate with `const char*` then you need to create an intermediate `string tmp = convert.str()`. Then the pointer to `tmp.c_str()` will be valid within the whole scope of `tmp`.